# Using foreach to show only certain elements in a list

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to c# and I've been trying to search for an answer/solution online but couldn't.

Basically, I've read a csv file in C#, separated the lines by a comma (',') and stored the three sets of data in a table. For eg, one line of the csv file is like: name, date1, date2

You can see the code below (a RHM class has also been created):

```
List<RHM> data1 = new List<RHM>();

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
lines.RemoveAt(0);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] entries = line.Split(',');
    RHM nRHM = new RMH 
    {
        Name = entries[0],
        Date1 = entries[1],
        Date2 = entries[2]
    };

    data1.Add(nRMH);

}
```

Now that I've imported it successfully, I just want to display e.g. the 5 line in the Name list. So far, I've only managed to display all the names using a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var RMH in data1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(RMH.Name);
}
```

I've tried using .skip but that will only remove one element from the list. I need a way to show for eg, lines 23, 34, 15.

Comment: You can use your variable _data1_ as it was an array _data1[4]_ is the fifth element (an RHM) added to that list, and thus _data1[4].Name_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access object in the list by index. So if you want the 23rd element you simply do `list[22]`. Index is `0` based that means `list[0]` will be the first element in the list. Here is an example how to access and use your object in list:

```
RHM 23rdItemInList = data1[22];
Console.WriteLine($"Name of item in list on index 22 is: {23rdItemInList.Name}");
```

---

Note if you remove an item from the list, the index will not correspond to actual line in the file. If it matters I would suggest to store line number in your object.

```
List<RHM> data1 = new List<RHM>();

List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
lines.RemoveAt(0);
int lineNumber = 1; //Here probably should be 2 because you skipping the first line in file with lines.RemoveAt(0);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] entries = line.Split(',');
    RHM nRHM = new RMH 
    {
        Line = lineNumber,
        Name = entries[0],
        Date1 = entries[1],
        Date2 = entries[2]
    };

    data1.Add(nRMH);
    lineNumber++;
}
```

Now you can get object by line number like so:

```
var 23rdLineData = data1.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Line == 23);
```

`FirstOrDefault` will return object of null if there is no record in the list with Line == 23. 
Check if object is found before using it

```
if(23rdLineData != null)
   Console.WriteLine($"Name on line 23 is {23rdLineData.Name}");
else
   Console.WriteLine("There is no data on line 23");
```

Comment: I've tried that before but for some reason it outputs the namespace name. I've also tried doing that in the foreach loop but that outputs the first character

Comment: I updated my answer with example and added some notes

Comment: He should check if the item index exists to avoid an exception

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achive your goal.

You could for example filter your list by any of your object fields by using LINQ like this:

```
List<RMH> results = data1.Where(d => d.Name == "HPBaxxter");
```

To filter by linenumber you can use TryGetValue for example:

```
RMH niceRMH;
int index = 23;
data1.TryGetValue(index, out niceRMH);
```

Comment: `TryGetValue` is method of `Dictionary` not a `List`